# irredicuble non-dimensional representation of the group $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

how to find matrices that correspond to generators in some irreducible no one-dimensional representation of the group $S_4$

Comment: non-dimensional?

Comment: no one-dimensional, sorry